# Retrieve "identical" complex object from database

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, iequalitycomparer

I have a table in LINQ to SQL called "Cars" that contains "Car" objects.

Each Car has an EngineID and a ColourID.

I have created a new, local Car object just in memory (not yet committed to the database).

I already have an IEqualityComparer written which works well in conjunction with .Contains to tell me TRUE/FALSE if any cars "identical" to the one I've created already exist.

But it returns a bool..

How can I actually get WHICH cars are identical..?

E.g. I want like something like..

```
IQueryable<Car> IdenticalCar = db.Cars.Equals(MyCar).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.Cars.Where(c=>c.Equals(MyCar)).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thx xandy. But when I try this code, while my existing .Contains method returns TRUE (identical objects exist) the .Equals then returns null and doesn't find any. Does .Equals definitely use the IEqualityComparer?? This doesn't seem to be working for me.. Cheers

Comment: Also: When I debug the above code, it never steps into my Equals routine.. So why isn't my own implementation of Equals being utilised when I use your code? Cheers..

Comment: Ok I sorted it out. I needed to implement from the IEquatable interface and implement my own Equals(Car) method as well as an Equals(obj) method and also GetHashCode method. Cheers